# Function with any number of arguments followed by a callback in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a type for an object that allows `string`s as keys and `function`s with any number of arguments, followed by a callback as values.

```js
// non working dummy code
type MyObject = Record<string, (...args: any[], callback(err: Error, result: any)>

// so that I can do this
const myObject = {
  foo: ((err, result) => {}),
  bar: ("arg", (err, result) => {}),
  baz: ("other", "args", true, 12, (err, result) => {}),
}
```

The background of this is that I am using the [`dbus` npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dbus) with which I can access Linux' DBUS api and I want to write types for specific functions of it.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of [Variadic](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) tuples in v4.0, you can now do this:

```
declare function foo<T extends any[], R>(...args: [...T, (err: Error, result: R) => any]): any;

foo((err, result: string) => {});

foo("args", (err, result: string) => {});
 
foo("other", "args", true, 12, (err, result: string) => {});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVJxwB4AVeEADwxFWAGd4pUBPAbQF0AaeAJQD4AFADoRsAOZ0AXPFYihJbgJAwY0gKIqcMbnDrIIGaTwCU8ALx9GLdselNmAbgBQTxIQFKVOkHoPS6GDBYqGKmFvAA3gC%20xs6u7gBE4nQJisra8Lr6hvABQSFhltGxTvDxOAIJOBgAFsqp8EkwEg2ByCDcAIwATGlemT7Z-oHBoeZFMQ5AA)

Answer (score 0):

The variadic arguments must be last in the function's signature.

```
type MyObject = Record<string, (callback(err: Error, result: any), ...args: any[])>

const myObject = {
  foo: ((err, result) => {}),
  bar: ((err, result) => {}, "arg"),
  baz: ((err, result) => {}, "other", "args", true, 12),
}
```

Comment: I know, but that does not solve the problem I have. How do I make it work the other way around. I cannot change the underlying code, but I have to write types for it